# How to do this in Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

Hello I am using jinja2 and I have a list of dictionaries that I am passing to jinja template.

```
{%for dict in list_of_dicts%}
<tr>
    {%for key in my_dict.keys()%}
    <td> {{my_dict.key}}</td> // Here i want to get value in my_dict with that particular key.
    {%endfor%}
</tr>
{%endfor %}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using just one variable in your for-loop, you just get the value and not the key name. You can use the alternative `key, value` syntax (as documented [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#for)) in a for loop to get the keys in a separate variable, like this:

```
{% for key, value in my_dict.iteritems() %}
    <td>{{ key }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to get the values in specific order? Let's say I provide list of keys whose values that I want to display  ['name', 'age'] in the particular order in the list?